# MVC 4 empty template page not found using model data

Tags: asp.net

I have started with an empty template in MVC 4 and I can access model data from views fine. However when I add a Shared folder, _Layout.cshtml and _ViewStart.cshtml, any time I try to output information from a model I get "page not found".

If I remove the model data from the markup and use plain HTML my layout and view load correctly. Any ideas?

I know I could of used the Internet Application template but I wanted to start from scratch and have already completed a lot of my model classes and configured DI.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had to clear the browser cache for the new changes to take effect!